# Inconsistency in knockout onchange event for checkbox at different browsers

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this code in my JS files for knockout:

```
function ProductOptionValue(id, name, option) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
    self.optionID = option;
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
}

self.optionValueChanged = function (optionValue, event) {
   if (optionValue.isSelected()) {
      // .....                                  
   } else {                                 
     // ...
   }
};
```

Binding looks like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: values">                                    
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected, attr: {id: 'ov'+id}, event: {change: $root.optionValueChanged}"/>    
        <label data-bind="text: name, attr: {for: 'ov'+id}"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Problem is that in IE (10) and Chrome when optionValueChanged is called I get old value for isSelected in optionValue, but in FF a new one, so all the logic becomes inverted.

Did anyone meet this inconcistency before? What should I do to prevent it.

I use version 2.2.1 of the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've subscribed to the observable I've bound to the checkbox, and that seems to work in IE 10 and Chrome and FF:

```
var isChecked = ko.observable(false);
isChecked.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
        // This is the new value of the checkbox observable
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to subscribe in event, so in some cases I can cancel it. Also function should be located in root model cause I use there some objects that ProductOptionValue shouldn't know about

Comment: There's no reason why you can't subscribe to a property in a child view model in your root model, as long as you have access to it from the root model. Could you not have the logic for cancelling the event into the subscribe method?

Comment: Yeah, I rewrite everything in way you suggested. It looks like everything works the same in all three browsers I checked

Comment: Cool, glad to be of help.